# Is there a way for AUTOML to learn legacy system by reading the code to customize future changes

Tags: web, cobol, automl

I have a fully functioning ERP software (written in COBOL using index file). I can put the entire software code and sample data files on Cloud. I need help with the following: 
AUTO ML to read the code and learn, improve the code, add new features as needed with minimum instructions, and create web based interface.

What steps do I need to take in order to get this project started?

How can I invite developers/collaborators?

Thank you in advance

Comment: _The irony is that recent advancements in deep learning areas such as natural language understanding(NLU) allow artificial intelligence(AI) agents to understand highly complex communication structures such as human conversations while we still can’t figure out highly structured texts such as computer programs._ [Using Deep Learning to Understand Your Source Code](https://medium.com/@jrodthoughts/using-deep-learning-to-understand-your-source-code-28e5c284bfda).

Comment: Any chance of sharing this ERP in Cobol source code ? I have being searching for ages for a functional legacy ERP (Dos) to get a view how they were made.